# Importing another PY script, calling func, returns None when it returns something?

Tags: python

Details: 2 python files, executing function from class in 1 file and outputting what it returns in another. (Problem is it returns None.) And yes, they are in the same directory of course.

What I tried/expected:

Script 1 (fun.py):

```
class cool:
    def add_together(a, b):
        anstomath = a + b
        cool_dict = {"answer": anstomath, "adding": "added 2 numbers"}
        return cool_dict
```

Script 2 (main.py): --> What I am running

```
from fun import cool

answer = cool.add_together(3, 4)
print(answer)
```

Output of main.py:

`None` when I expected **7**

IF I print **anstomath** variable in fun.py, it prints 7. Why does main.py not work when I am doing the same?

Comment: I tried it an obtained this output: `{'answer': 7, 'adding': 'added 2 numbers'}`. Which is expected, as your method `add_together()` returns a `cool_dict` dictionary.

Comment: You don't need to nest your function into a class, if you don't use class- or object properties in it. Simply put only the function definiton into your `fun.py` file and `import fun` (or `from fun import add_together`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce, as well. Are you sure your files look exactly like that? What version of Python are you using? Are you running this in a terminal, an IDE, or somewhere else?

Comment: @MarianD yes, but i have more functions in the class. and i want it done in the class

Comment: @CrazyChucky python 3.9, both files in same folder, running in cmd prompt.

Comment: Just to clarify, since you mention having more methods in the class. You have tested the minimal version shown here? Copied what's shown here into blank new files and run that, without any of your other code present?

Comment: @Jay - *"...and i want it done in the class"* - **Why?** Do you use class- or instance variables in them?

Comment: @Jay, BTW functions in classes are called *methods* and require *one additional parameter as a first one* (named `cls` or `self` by convention), if they are not declared as "static".

Comment: @Jay, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242638/7023590) (particularly the second half of it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is missing `@staticmethod` before the `def add_together(a, b):`

The code should look like:

```
class cool:
    @staticmethod
    def add_together(a, b):
        anstomath = a + b
        cool_dict = {"answer": anstomath, "adding": "added 2 numbers"}
        return cool_dict
```

and the other file should look like that

```
from fun import cool

answer = cool.add_together(3, 4)
print(answer)
```

output =

```
{'answer': 7, 'adding': 'added 2 numbers'}
```

Comment: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when i put @staticmethod

Comment: @Jay That doesn't make much sense, unless you've also declared the parameter `self` in the method declaration.